# chef not_if inside a only_if

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Can I have a not_if inside a only_if block like the

```
 only_if{ A == "A" && not_if { ::File.exists(/a.txt)}}
```

My question is will such structure work ? Or do I need to do it in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it a different way. `only_if{ A == "A" && !::File.exists(/a.txt) }` or similar.

Comment: Either of these answers work. If you aren't seeing the behavior you want, something else is likely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

hard to say without real code to look at it, but have you tried this structure?

```
only_if { A == "A" }  
not_if { ::File.exists(/a.txt) }
```

Comment: yes, the structure above does not run the not_if block for some reason.

Comment: It only runs the `not_if` is the first guard passes.

Comment: that's right, it won't run `not_if` if `only_if` ends up being false... this is the [concept of condtional short circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), which is definitely how you want it to work